# URL to RABL template from rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

My controller looks like this:

```
module Algo
  class GraphsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html, :json

    def show
      @graph = Graph.find(params[:id])
      gon.rabl '../../app/views/algo/graphs/show.json.rabl', as: 'graph' # Hmm
      respond_with(@graph)
    end
  end
end
```

See the `gon.rabl` statement, which I'm not too happy with.

Again, this is from a Engine controller, currently mounted inside its `test/dummy/` directory.

Any tips to how I get clean this up?

Comment: What is the `gon.rabl` statement doing?  There's no `gon` var/method in the code that you're showing.

Comment: Very sorry late answer. The `gon.rabl` statement is from the [Gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon).